# is it possible to open the plugin extension window with a url?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension. Now, My usecase is that, Clicking on the plugin icon should hit a url hosted at a server, and the response for the url should be rendered in the plugin window. Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean the extension's navigable page within the browser tab, or the popup that flys out from the button?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `<iframe>` inside your HTML will serve your purpose, unless you run into a page that actively prevents framing; then I don't think this is directly possible.